# How to specify nested partitions in merge query while trying to merge incremental data with a base table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to merge a dataframe that contains incremental data into my base table as per the databricks documentation.

```
base_delta.alias('base') \
    .merge(source=kafka_df.alias('inc'), 
           condition='base.key1=ic.key1 and base.key2=inc.key2') \
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
    .execute()
```

The above operation is working fine but it takes lot time as expected since there are lot of unwanted partitions that are being scanned.
I came across a databricks documentation [here](https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into.html), a merge query with partitions specified in it.

Code from that link:

```
spark.sql(s"""
     |MERGE INTO $targetTableName
     |USING $updatesTableName
     |ON $targetTableName.par IN (1,0) AND $targetTableName.id = $updatesTableName.id
     |WHEN MATCHED THEN
     |  UPDATE SET $targetTableName.ts = $updatesTableName.ts
     |WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     |  INSERT (id, par, ts) VALUES ($updatesTableName.id, $updatesTableName.par, $updatesTableName.ts)
 """.stripMargin)
```

The partitions are specified in the `IN` condition as `1,2,3...` But in my case, the table is first partitioned on `COUNTRY` values `USA, UK, NL, FR, IND` and then every country has partition on `YYYY-MM` Ex: `2020-01, 2020-02, 2020-03`
How can I specify the partition values if I have nested structure like I mentioned above ?
Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: do you have these columns (`COUNTRY`, etc.) in the updates table?

Comment: I am passing COUNTRY as a job parameter to filter data from the source tables. So all I have to do is use the COUNTRY as my main partition column and then pass on the YYYY-MM I am deriving from a piece of code as the sub partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that & it's really recommended, because Delta Lake needs to scan all the data that are matching to the `ON` condition. If you're using Python API, you just need to use correct SQL expression as `condition`, and you can put restrictions on the partition columns into it, something like this in your case (`date` is the column from the update date):

```sql
base.country = 'country1' and base.date = inc.date and 
  base.key1=inc.key1 and base.key2=inc.key2
```

if you have multiple countries, then you can use `IN ('country1', 'country2')`, but it would be easier to have `country` inside your update dataframe and match using `base.country = inc.country`

Comment: Understood and tested this. It is working.